# Updating a column in dataframe having dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a column named 'hierarchy' in pandas dataframe which is having dictionary values

```
{'5ff70ec16e8fa91c6462a47f': {'title': 'TP Layer', 'joinBy': '4a850c44-0107-48fb-a5e3-14a8e4cd44ab'}}
{'5fff3c3318d71e001221cc5b': {'title': 'Legal Entities', 'joinBy': '20e49f0a-4dca-43a3-8a5c-2ef1607c5e5f'}}
{'5ff76134930ddee5814becba': {'title': 'Line Item', 'joinBy': '5a8295e8-e006-4a6a-98b9-64587bb679c6'}}
nan
nan
nan
{'5ff74bc8930ddef3be4becb5': {'title': 'Relationship', 'joinBy': 'ea307ebb-1b40-4c6b-b922-b7d6d6920e03'}}
nan
nan
{'600062d318d71e001221cc5d': {'title': 'ProjeX V2 Periods', 'joinBy': '1e09f4d0-2736-4a38-a122-ac8e7ee35367'}}
```

I want to extract the title and joinBy and create separate columns for that in dataframe, so, the result should appear like

```
title                           joinBy
TP Layer                        4a850c44-0107-48fb-a5e3-14a8e4cd44ab
Legal Entities                  20e49f0a-4dca-43a3-8a5c-2ef1607c5e5f
nan                             nan
```

Does anyone has any idea, how to do this?

Comment: Do the dictionary values have only one value?

Comment: yes, it has just one value.

Comment: I would use apply function - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0):

With `df` referring to the input dataframe described in your post, the following will add new columns to your dataframe and fill them with `"title"` and `"joinBy"` values extracted from the `"hierarchy"` column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for i, entry in enumerate(df["hierarchy"]):
    if type(entry) == dict:
        k = list(entry.keys())[0]
        df.at[i,"title"] = entry[k]["title"]
        df.at[i,"joinBy"] = entry[k]["joinBy"]
    else:
        df.at[i,"title"] = np.nan
        df.at[i,"joinBy"] = np.nan
```

Note that I have worked with `np.nan` in my snippet. If you want your `nan`s differently in the created dataframe, you would have to amend the code accordingly.